# How do I Create a global class variable in Python

Tags: python, class, global

I want to use a class in Python to simulate a 'struct' in C++. Also, I need it in global form as I am using it in many functions and I do not want to pass parameters.

How do I do this(create global objects of a class).

My attempt was :

```
class MyClass():
//Class Constuctor

global ob1 = Myclass()

def func1():
   ob1.name = "Hello World"

def func2():
    print(ob1.name)

func1()
func2()
```

This gives me an 'Invalid Syntax' error, how did I go wrong, or is there a more efficient method to do this?
Note that I have like 10 values, so the class is going to be a pain anyway.

Comment: Your code isn't valid, so we can't reproduce the syntax error. Please post a [mcve]. Also, I'd advise against globals. It makes it difficult to reason about your code, dependencies aren't explicit, and separation of concerns is easy to violate. It will lead to poorly structured code unless you are very disciplined and know what you are doing (which I don't think I would attempt). It is also more difficult to test as the state between tests can change.

Answer (score 1):

In your code it is not necessary to explicitly place the global modifier, this variable is global by default.

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""

ob1 = MyClass()

def func1():
   ob1.name = "Hello World"

def func2():
    print(ob1.name)

func1()
func2()
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```

In addition the use of global is as follows:

```
global variable

variable = your_value
```

Comment: `ob1` is a global in your code. `'ob1' in globals()` is `True`

Comment: You're right, what I meant is that it is not necessary to use the global modifier in the code.

Comment: Okay, I see the distinction now.

Comment: I see, will try this :) Thanks